# Run jenkins agent in docker container, issue with jenkins pipeline and /var/run/docker.socket

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-machine

I've created image that use for jenkins agent slave
Here it is: https://hub.docker.com/r/kondaurov/jenkins_agent/~/dockerfile/

Than i run it:

```
docker run -d -p 2222:22 --name=jenkins_agent -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v kondaurov/jenkins_agent
```

Then i create new node in jenkins and it connects successfully via ssh

I try to run this pipeline:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
            docker {
                label 'agent01'
                image 'hello-world'
            }


    }

    stages {

        stage('Compile') {

            steps {
                sh 'whoami'
                sh 'echo $PATH'

            }

        }


    }

}
```

agent01 - is a container with my slave image

But it fails..

> Started by user Alexander Mac Replayed #18
>
> > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Setting origin to https://github.com/kondaurov-scala/snippets.git
> >     git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/kondaurov-scala/snippets.git # timeout=10 Fetching
> >     origin... Fetching upstream changes from origin
> >     git --version # timeout=10 using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
> >     git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* Seen branch in repository origin/1.1.0 Seen branch in repository origin/master Seen 2 remote
> >     branches Obtained Jenkinsfile from
> >     5d917470103056b70398465c0d8a56b127f9e036 [Pipeline] node Running on
> >     agent01 in
> >     /home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q
> >     [Pipeline] { [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
> >     [Pipeline] checkout
> >     git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> >     git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/kondaurov-scala/snippets.git # timeout=10 Fetching
> >     without tags Fetching upstream changes from
> >     https://github.com/kondaurov-scala/snippets.git
> >     git --version # timeout=10 using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
> >     git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/kondaurov-scala/snippets.git
> >     +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* Checking out Revision 5d917470103056b70398465c0d8a56b127f9e036 (1.1.0) Commit message: "ref"
> >     git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> >     git checkout -f 5d917470103056b70398465c0d8a56b127f9e036
> >     git rev-list 5d917470103056b70398465c0d8a56b127f9e036 # timeout=10 [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] withEnv [Pipeline] {
> >     [Pipeline] stage [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup) [Pipeline] sh
> >     [hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q]
> >     Running shell script
> >     + docker pull hello-world Using default tag: latest latest: Pulling from library/hello-world 5b0f327be733: Pulling fs layer 5b0f327be733:
> >     Verifying Checksum 5b0f327be733: Download complete 5b0f327be733: Pull
> >     complete Digest:
> >     sha256:b2ba691d8aac9e5ac3644c0788e3d3823f9e97f757f01d2ddc6eb5458df9d801
> >     Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest [Pipeline] }
> >     [Pipeline] // stage [Pipeline] sh
> >     [hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q]
> >     Running shell script
> >     + docker inspect -f . hello-world . [Pipeline] withDockerContainer agent01 seems to be running inside container
> >     c6ad60fd4215a35009accd0be49fbe1ebb583b18b12bf87ba80141b63ae9221a but
> >     /home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q
> >     could not be found among [/var/run/docker.sock] but
> >     /home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q@tmp
> >     could not be found among [/var/run/docker.sock] $ docker run -t -d -u
> >     1000:1000 -w
> >     /home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q
> >     -v /home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q:/home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q:rw,z -v /home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q@tmp:/home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q@tmp:rw,z
> >     -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat hello-world [Pipeline] // withDockerContainer [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // withEnv
> >     [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // node [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
> >     java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'hello-world'. Error: docker:
> >     Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262:
> >     starting container process caused "exec: \"cat\": executable file not
> >     found in $PATH".  at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.run(DockerClient.java:138)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:179)
> >       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:224)
> >       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:150)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
> >       at
> >     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
> >       at
> >     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
> >       at
> >     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
> >       at
> >     com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:19)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:128)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:63)    at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:116)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.DockerPipelineScript.runImage(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/DockerPipelineScript.groovy:57)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.configureRegistry(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:68)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.run(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.checkoutAndRun(jar:file:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:60)
> >       at ***cps.transform***(Native Method)   at
> >     com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
> >       at
> >     com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
> >       at
> >     com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
> >       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor603.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
> >     com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
> >       at
> >     com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
> >       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)     at
> >     com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)     at
> >     com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)     at
> >     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
> >       at
> >     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
> >       at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
> >       at
> >     org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
> >       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> >     hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
> >       at
> >     jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
> >       at
> >     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> >       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> >       at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"cat\": executable file not found in $PATH". --< that's your error :)

Comment: @Sergiu, i don't think so, i believe this one important: withDockerContainer agent01 seems to be running inside container c6ad60fd4215a35009accd0be49fbe1ebb583b18b12bf87ba80141b63ae9221a but /home/jenkins/workspace/hello_world_1.1.0-NAIZYV5H2QFOICXMDYZJM3A6XMQ4YL2QYG5ZWJDDWOEWF27RHL7Q could not be found among [/var/run/docker.sock]

Comment: Did you made sure that the users have the right UID and GID inside the container?

Comment: @Sergiu, I can ssh to my agent as jenkins and run docker ps for e.g, doesn't this mean that rights are correct? Rights of what? /var/run/docker.sock?

Comment: Yes the right to run Docker.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, that message:

```
sl01978v-98210312 seems to be running inside container d93e0112b277e94c11bac40af30ddd13ef39cb312caca839497e012cd71bdf86
but /opt/jenkins/workspace/gopvolging_jenkins-somebranch could not be found among [jenkins_slave]
but /opt/jenkins/workspace/gopvolging_jenkins-somebranch@tmp could not be found among [jenkins_slave]
```

... was caused by the fact that the jenkins slave (which is a docker container) didn't have any volume or mount for the workspace, so the `--volume-from` option that Jenkins automatically passes in a DiD scenario couldn't be added. It instead tried to pass the workspace in `-v`, but that wasn't shared with the Jenkins slave container, so it kept waiting endlessly on the first `sh` command. Adding a volume for the Jenkins workspace solved it:

```
sl01978v-fbd455e0 seems to be running inside container 0f0090afbcece077f492be581170bf9ffb778c75e23144ccf303e9f47e9cfdd5
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /opt/jenkins/workspace/gopvolging_jenkins-somebranch --volumes-from 0f0090afbcece077f492be581170bf9ffb778c75e23144ccf303e9f47e9cfdd5 ...
```

(the magic being `--volume-from`)

Comment: `--volume-from` didn't helped me. At least test that with it. For me it solved to mount it twice. So here something like `<path to workspace in did container>:/opt/jenkins/workspace/`
You pointed me in right direction

Answer (score 0):

Try to link the remote root directory of the slave container to your host `/tmp` folder.
It appears to be `/home/jenkins/` in your case

```
docker run -d -p 2222:22 --name=jenkins_agent -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp:/home/jenkins
```